# parameter as current date in function in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I created a function in codeigniter and I want to set the current date as the default value of a parameter of a function but it does not work.

```
function Sales($deyt1=date('Y-m-d'), $deyt2=date('Y-m-d')) {
     .....
     .....
}
```

how can I assign a current date as default? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign default date inside the function. Because parameters assign the value when the function got called.

```
function Sales($deyt1='', $deyt2='') {

  if($deyt1 == '' )
      $deyt1 = date('Y-m-d');
  if($deyt2 == '' )
      $deyt2 = date('Y-m-d');    

     .....
     .....
}
```

Comment: it cannot be done like that because if i pass a value to the function the values will be changed. what i want is that when there is no date passed to the function, the current date will be used.

Comment: thanks. so it should be validated inside the function rather than have default values. I did assign default values in strings and numeric and it worked but not in parameter with function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is better to place your date logic inside the function, rather than setting it as  a parameter and use conditional formating.

Eg :

```
function Sales($deyt1=null, $deyt2=null) {

$d1 = ($deyt1 != '')?$deyt1:date('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: thanks. i thought it can be done with dates. i did it with string and numeric values like this: `function Sales($para1='OK',$para2=3)` and it worked.